# How to set different opacity to body and boder using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a customized cursor. I am trying to make a circular cursor where just borders will be fully opaque while its interior must be transparent just like circular ring. Below is the CSS snippet for reference:-

```
.app-cursor {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

The problem I am facing is in the last two lines, either the whole cursor is becoming transparent or the
the middle portion is becoming fully opaque, how to deal with the situation.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the ```opacity``` declaration and set the ```background: transparent;``` Keeping the border set of course.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

1. You need to take out `opacity: 0;` and change `border: 1px solid white;` to `border: 1px solid black;`.
2. Finally, You need to add `background-color: transparent;`

```css
.app-cursor {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="app-cursor"></span>
```